# How can I use cURL with OpenRefine?

Tags: curl, openrefine

I'm trying to connect to an API on OpenRefine that only works on a cURL request with an OAth, and they gave the following example:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://apitest.api.com/' \

--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \

--header 'Accept: application/json' \

--header 'Authorization: Bearer ***************' \

--data-raw '{

  "Name": {

    "FirstName": "BOB",

    "LastName": "SMITH"

  },

  "Address": {

    "Addr1": "123 23RD ST",

    "City": "NEW YORK",

    "State": "NY",

    "Zip": "10010"

  }

}'
```

which I changed to (using GREL)

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://apitest.api.com/' \

--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \

--header 'Accept: application/json' \

--header 'Authorization: Bearer ***************' \

--data-raw '{

  "Name": {

    "FirstName": cells['FirstName'].value,

    "LastName": cells['LastName'].value

  },

  "Address": {

    "Addr1": cells['StreetAddress'].value,

    "City": cells['City'].value,

    "State": cells['State'].value,

    "Zip": cells['Zip'].value

  }

}'
```

which gives me a `Parsing error at offset 7: Bad negative number`

I've also placed the `Authorization: Bearer ***************` and `Accept: application/json` in the `HTTP headers` area, with no luck either.

I've also tried:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer ******" -d "{
  \"Name\": {
    \"FirstName\": \" + cells['FirstName'].value + \",
    \"LastName\": \" + cells['LastName'].value + \"
  },
  \"Address\": {
    \"Addr1\": \" + cells['Street'].value + \",
    \"City\": \" + cells['City'].value + \",
    \"State\": \" + cells['State'].value + \",
    \"Zip\": \" + cells['Zip'].value + \"
  }
}" "https://apitest.api.com/"
```

which worked with explicit data in my console. (I wasn't receiving the parsing error anymore, but I wasn't getting anything else either.)

Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain where you are putting this code? In OpenRefine? At the shell command line? Somewhere else? curl doesn't speak GREL. Does the apitest endpoint that you're sending to understand it? Can you take a step back and explain your overall setup? I think I'm missing some key piece(s) of context.

Comment: In "Add column by fetching URLs based on column Name". I had tested it in my shell command line. I have a cleaned and filtered data set in OpenRefine that I want to pull more contact information for the people, based on their Name and address. I was under the impression from things I read elsewhere that you are able to fetch URLs with cURL somehow. I could be wrong. Maybe the correct way to do this is via Python/Jython. Just struggling a bit.

Comment: Got it! OpenRefine has the URL fetch functionality built in, so there's no need for the curl utility.  However, it only supports GET (not POST) using query parameters in the URL (not the request body). If your endpoint supports GET requests of the form https://apitest.api.com?query={Name: {Firstname: "Ezra"...}} or something similar, you can fetch from them using OpenRefine, but if it's limited to POST, you'll need to use a different tool (although you could use OpenRefine to write a file of curl commands to execute).

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the explanation! Do you, by any chance, have any link to explain your last line?